# Does Grit works with Windows 7 well?

Tags: ruby, git, windows-7, grit

I have tried the last day to work with the Ruby gem `git` (version 1.2.5), but I am not sure that it works well enough. I stumbled over `grit`, which is more active, but was not able to get it working under Windows 7. Do you have used `grit` under Windows 7, especially to use the methods `status`, `add` and others?

My working environment:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

  - git 1.2.5
  - grit 2.4.1
- I used the two only in a shell / IRB environment, to get a feeling if one or the other would be a good fit. I want it then to integrate it in my Rails application (as part of a Rake task).

Comment: Which Ruby version and Gems do you use and which Windows 7 do you use 32 or 64 Bit? The gem "git" is way more powerful then "grit". But grit has a better interface IMO.

Comment: By the way there is another Ruby interface to git called [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) that is based on [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2).  libgit2 was written to [compile on Windows platforms](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/wiki/Building-libgit2-on-Windows).  Rugged currently has some [build issues on Windows](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/issues/43) but when these are resolved you should be able to use it.  Rugged [apparently will replace](https://github.com/github/gollum/issues/356) grit on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point and time the answer to your question apparently is "no".  The [grit gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/grit) requires the posix-spawn gem which, according to the [project page](https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn), currently does not support Windows:

> Potentially portable - abstracts lower-level process and stream
>   management APIs so the class can be made to work on platforms like
>   Java and Windows where UNIX process spawning and stream APIs are not
>   supported.

The key above is *"can be made to work on platforms like... Windows"*.

Answer (score 0):

I see a link on github related to this post - https://github.com/mojombo/grit/issues/4

Not sure how to use it though as I don't see open3_detach.rb file in Grit code.